# Nginx drops ActionCable connections immediately after they're established

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy, actioncable

Using puma with Rails 6 running behind Nginx. The nginx config looks like this:

```
upstream APPNAME {
  server unix:/tmp/APPNAME.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  # ... server_name, ssl_certificate, etc.
  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://APPNAME;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
  location @APPNAME {
    proxy_pass http://APPNAME;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

When an ActionCable connection comes in from a browser, it is able to subscribe to the channel and receives responses. But it never receives any "ping" messages and it continues to reconnect (every 10 seconds in my case).

Using `curl` to test the connection directly, it works correctly when running puma directly on the server (on a localhost port since the config uses a Unix socket).

```sh
time curl --trace-ascii curl-dump.txt -i -k -N \
  -H "Host: <REPLACE_WITH_HOSTNAME>" \
  -H "Connection: Upgrade" \
  -H "Upgrade: websocket" \
  -H "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" \
  -H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: BOGUS+KEY+HERE+IS+FINE==" \
  http://localhost:3000/cable
```

But when the connection URL is change to point to the nginx port number, the result is similar to the browser: it never gets any "ping" messages.

Answer (score 1):

I had assumed the configuration within the `location @APPNAME` section would be used for other locations that call `proxy_pass`, but in retrospect I see that it's not at all, which is why the `proxy_set_header` directives have to be repeated.

So the `location /cable` section needs to include *all* directives that make `location @APPNAME` work correctly. I found that adding `proxy_redirect off;` fixed this problem.

So the following location configuration fixed the problem:

```
  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://APPNAME;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
```